# Raising a Matrix to the nth power in C

Tags: c

```
void matRaise( int n, int m, int ***a){
    int **x;
    x = (int **) calloc(n, sizeof(int *) * (n));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        *(x + i) = (int *)calloc(n, sizeof(int) * (n));


    int **y;
    y = (int **) calloc(n, sizeof(int *) * (n));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        *(y + i) = (int *)calloc(n, sizeof(int) * (n));


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        x[i][i]=1;


    for(int p = 0; p < m; p++){
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                y[i][j]=0;
                for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                    y[i][j] += *(*(x + i) + k) * (*(*(*a + k) + j));
            }

        x = y;
    }
    *a = x;
}
```

For let's say the 2 2
2 2
matrix raised to the 4th power this is the output

576 3456

576 3456

I really don't get what I am doing wrong. I know I am not using the most efficient algorithm for this kind of problem, but since I've started solving it this way I really want to know where's the mistake.

Comment: 1. Are you getting the correct result for the 2nd power, and this matrix? 2. Are you getting the correct result for diagonal matrices? 3. What are m, n, p? 4. Why is a a pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer?

Comment: Hi, are you sure for your x[i][i] in the third for ?? and please use better varible names it's really hard to understand here ...

Comment: @einpoklum yea sorry my code is a bit messy; m represent the power u raise the matrix to; n it s number of rows and columns; p well it s i think self-explanatory because i want to actually get to the power of mth.

Comment: @AlexB that s for the identity matrix

Comment: @einpoklum i am getting the correct result  just for the first multiplication between matrix X and matrix A, and i am using a pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer because i want to modify the value of A so i need to work with its address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x = y` doesn't do what you think it does.

`x` and `y` are both *pointers*. They may point to something complex, but themselves they are no more than addresses. When you assign one pointer to another, you're replacing one address with another.

After executing this assignment instruction, `x` and `y` point to the same place, and your modification of values through `y` also modifies the values stored in `x`.

More generally, be very careful with the representation of complex data types in C. Consider implementing helper functions for allocation, element access, copying etc.

Comment: So, basically what you're saying is that if x and y are allocated memory in the same function they will point to the same place ?